# Visual Studio 2008 performing like VBA

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba, excel, vsto

I know about VSTO/VSTA, and I also know that some VBA functionality (with .NET syntax of course) can be done in .NET. There is definitely a learning curve going from VBA to .NET *without* VSTO. My question though is, can everything that is done in VBA somehow be recreated in .NET without VSTO?

The reason is because I am converting my VBA application into .NET for several reasons: I want to take advantage of OO, my class libraries will be better available for use, and for fun. I wouldn't be too happy if I got so far in only to learn of some limitations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you'll run into any actual limitations. However, VBA exposes some features that take substantially more effort within .NET. Are you interfacing with applications within the MS Office Suite? VBA exposes methods for this. VBA also allows for the simulation of keyboard presses, which isn't as straightforward in .Net.

Comment: I am working only with Excel in the MS Office Suite. For the sake of simplicty, I have a application that loads a new workbook and fills in the first 10 rows in column A. I haven't found a way to mimick the "SelectDown" feature in VBA. Not that I need you to answer that question for me.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by VBA exposes methods? I know that it has some of the same methods that I can gain access to.

Comment: Check out this link from MSDN that has helped me in the past when making these decisions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: If you're still having trouble with the SelectDown feature, be sure to post another question, we'd love to help!